# TikZ pictures does not appear in poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, posters

I'm making a poster with LaTeX using the template available here http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/eglen/damtp/cuposter/.

For some reason, images created using TikZ do not appear in the poster. It compiles just fine, and other images added using `\includegraphics{}` appear. Here is, what seems to me a relevant portion of the code. The same piece of code, along with the initial TikZ includes and definitions worked fine in the LNCS template. Please let me know if I can add anything more informative.

```
\documentclass[noback]{cuposter}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Tikz stuff
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,chains}

\tikzset{latent/.style={circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=1pt, 
minimum size=20pt, font=\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont},
obs/.style={latent,fill=gray!25},
const/.style={rectangle, inner sep=0pt},
factor/.style={rectangle, fill=black,minimum size=5pt, inner sep=0pt},
>={triangle 45}}

\pgfdeclarelayer{b}
\pgfdeclarelayer{f}
\pgfsetlayers{b,main,f}

% shapename, fitlist, caption, pos
\newcommand{\plate}[4]{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{b}
    \node (invis#1) [draw, color=white, inner sep=2pt,rectangle, fit=#2] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{f}
    \node (#1) [draw,inner sep=0pt, rectangle,fit=(invis#1),#3,#4] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{document}

.
.
.

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [matrix,matrix anchor=mid, column sep=5pt, row sep=20pt] {
    % hidden layer
    \node (inv) [draw=none] {}; &
    \node (inv) [draw=none] {}; &
    \node (inv) [draw=none] {}; &
    \node (h1) [latent] {$h_1$}; &
    \node (h2) [latent] {$h_2$}; &
    \node (hlabel) [draw=none] {$\mathbf{h}$};
    \\

    % visible layer
    \node (inv) [draw=none] {}; &
    \node (inv) [draw=none] {}; &
    \node (x1) [latent] {$v_1$}; &
    \node (x2) [latent] {$v_2$}; &
    \node (x3) [latent] {$v_3$}; &
    \node (x4) [latent] {$v_4$}; &
    \node (xlabel) [draw=none] {$\mathbf{v}$}; &        
    \node (inv) [draw=none] {}; &       
    \\
    };

    % connections
    \draw [-] (x1) -- node [left=2pt] {} (h1);
    \draw [-] (x1) -- node [left=2pt] {} (h2);
    \draw [-] (x2) -- node [left=2pt] {} (h1);
    \draw [-] (x2) -- node [left=2pt] {} (h2);
    \draw [-] (x3) -- node [left=2pt] {} (h1);
    \draw [-] (x3) -- node [left=2pt] {} (h2);
    \draw [-] (x4) -- node [left=2pt] {} (h1);
    \draw [-] (x4) -- node [right=2pt] {W} (h2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\caption{A simple Restricted Boltzmann Machine with four visible, two hidden, and no bias units.}
\label{fig:rbm}
\end{figure}

.
.
.

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Remove the `figure` environment (cuposter can't use floating environments)...

Comment: Not sure what is the expected output, but I get a blue frame with the University of Cambridge logo and _above of that frame_ a tiny graph, which is the result of your tikz environment. Of course I had to follow the route latex->dvips->pstopdf to get that result. If `figure` environment is dropped, the picture appears inside the frame, instead of at top, which I think could be part of your problem.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks! That worked. Did you find this information in the .sty file? Where was this given? But now the picture is very small, as JLDiaz pointed out. I'm trying to fix this now :)

Comment: @user1953384 I found this information in `poster.tex`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit But where exactly? I'm sorry if this is obvious in some way. Please bear with me.

Comment: @user1953384 In `poster.tex`, no figure is floating.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Could you make that an answer?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Care for an answer?

Comment: @PaulGaborit could you make an answer from your comment(s)? Otherwise someone could make a CW answer so this doesn't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cuposter` class does not allow the usage of floating environments like `figure` or `table`.

Remove the `figure` environment and your picture appears.